# Qt - not all widgets refreshed after stylesheet change

Tags: qt, qtstylesheets

I have style manager, so user can change stylesheet and palette in runtime. But after this operation, not all widgets are "restyled". New look is applied when widget is recreated. Same code called from main window constructor is working like expected. Is exists any global signal which notify all widgets that they should refresh palette and stylesheet?

```
QFile file(":/qss/default.qss");
file.open(QFile::ReadOnly);
QString styleSheet = QLatin1String(file.readAll());
qApp->setStyleSheet(styleSheet);
QPalette p = qApp->palette();
p.setColor(QPalette::Window, QColor(53,53,53));
p.setColor(QPalette::Button, QColor(53,53,53));
p.setColor(QPalette::Highlight, QColor(175,0,0));
p.setColor(QPalette::ButtonText, QColor(255,255,255));
p.setColor(QPalette::WindowText, QColor(255,255,255));
qApp->setPalette(p);
```

Comment: How do you set stylesheet and palette? Do all your widgets have parent? Is there anything common in those widgets, which do not change? Answering your question - no, there is no such signal for user to call, but, if you're doing everything right, the change should occur automatically.

Comment: I updated my first post with code example. This code is called from modal StyleDialog. Some widgets apply new palette and stylesheet automatically but some not (like MainMenu where text is still black but should be white). Should I enumerate all widgets and apply palette on each widget?

Comment: I'm pretty sure, enumerating widgets and applying palette to each should solve the problem, nevertheless, it is a bad solution. I've created a minimal application with a modal dialog, which does exactly the same, as your code, and it worked as expected. Some time ago I wrote a program with a similar functionality (setting palette to qApp; I didn't set stylesheet, 'cause they are interchangeable) and it also worked perfectly. So I still think, there is a fundamental error in your program, which causes such behavior. May be you change those widgets palette or stylesheet somewhere else in code?

Comment: Nope, only in StyleManager modal dialog. Note that even this dialog is not styled, but if I reopen this dialog, then is ok. I'm using QT 4.8